# Formatting real value returned by query from a database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql-9.1

I am using postgresql.The table in my database have column with type `REAL`.When real value having more than seven zeros postgresql stores it for example as 1e+007.When it is retrieved by query,value return also as 1e+007.But I need the value as 10000000 .What is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have more problems than that if you use floating point numbers for things they aren't suitable for, including pretty much anything where you care about the exact presentation of the number.

I would recommend that you use `NUMERIC`, a base-10 (decimal) number data type that lets you control precision and scale. See [Numeric types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html). `NUMERIC` *is* slower to perform calculations with and consumes more storage so it isn't always the right answer, but it's ideal for a great many applications.

You *can* use floats, it's just harder because you can't safely compare for exact equality, have to use rounding and formatting functions for display, etc.

Example:

```
regress=> select '1.2'::float8 - '1.0'::float8;
       ?column?       
----------------------
 0.199999999999999956
(1 row)

regress=> select '1.2'::numeric - '1.0'::numeric;
 ?column? 
----------
      0.2
(1 row)
```

Another common solution to problems like these is to use an application defined fixed point representation. If you need (say) 2 decimal places, you just store the number `2000.11` as `200011` in the database, multiplying by 100. This is a common technique in financial applications though it's now more common to use proper decimal data types.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL `CAST`. Works for me in DB2

```
select cast(cast(1e+007 as real) as decimal (15,2)) from sysibm.sysdummy1;
10000000.00
```

You can set decimal places as per your desired value (15,0).

Comment: If you leave out the `sysdummy1` part it should also work in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(1e+007::real, '9999999999')
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: if the value to be cast contain more than 10 places,what is the common solution